# procedure is deleting data instead of inserting

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure as the following:

```
create procedure MoveDailyData
    @date1 bigint
    as
    declare @datenow bigint
    set @datenow = datediff(S,'01/01/1970',getdate())
    if ((@datenow)-@date1)>=86400
    begin
     insert into FinalLogs(problem,channel_number,username,app_id,Is_On,logtype,viewing_channel,playtime,macaddress,wifimacaddress,seen,version,date) 
     select problem,channel_number,username,app_id,Is_On,logtype,viewing_channel,playtime,macaddress, wifimacaddress,seen,version,date from DayTempTable
     delete from DayTempTable where (@datenow-@date1)>=86400
     end
     else select 'Not Yet';
```

The procedure should copy the data from 1 temporary table to the final one (in a daily schedule ) and after that delete that data from the temporary table. Instead, I have been noticing that every couple of days, the data does not get copied, but only deleted from the temporary table, and so I have lost a great amount of relevant data. 
the `date` column is a `bigint` (dates are saved as `unix time`). Is there something that I am doing wrong in this procedure?

Comment: You are inserting the whole table but only deleting part?  If the insert failed it should not get to the delete.

Comment: @Frisbee exactly, because the temporary table should however save some data, like a couple of minutes or so (by request of the client). About the second point, I completely agree with you, but somehow it does get to the delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. No explicit BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT / ROLLBACK around the `INSERT` and `DELETE` to group them as an atomic operation.
2. No TRY / CATCH structure to manage `COMMIT` vs `ROLLBACK`.
3. Why are you using UNIX time instead of actual `DATETIME` values?
4. Why no `WHERE` condition on the `SELECT` that feeds the `INSERT`?
5. But most directly related to the stated question: the entire `DayTempTable` table gets deleted because the `WHERE` condition of the `DELETE` statement is a simple boolean expression and does not reference any field of that table. Meaning, if `(@datenow-@date1)>=86400` evaluates to `true`, then all rows will be deleted. Else, no rows will be deleted. If you want a subset of rows to be deleted, you need to actually filter the table ;-).
6. An alternate approach to the `INSERT` then `DELETE` within an explicit Transaction is to handle both operations at the same time via the `OUTPUT` clause:

   ```sql
   DELETE tbl
   FROM   DayTempTable tbl
   OUTPUT DELETED.problem, DELETED.channel_number, DELETED.username, DELETED.app_id,
          DELETED.Is_On, DELETED.logtype, DELETED.viewing_channel, DELETED.playtime,
          DELETED.macaddress, DELETED.wifimacaddress, DELETED.seen, DELETED.version,
          DELETED.date
   INTO   FinalLogs (problem, channel_number, username, app_id, Is_On, logtype,
                     viewing_channel, playtime, macaddress, wifimacaddress, seen,
                     version, date)
   WHERE  (@datenow - tbl.[date_field]) >= 86400;
   ```

   And then you don't need the explicit Transaction (i.e. BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT / ROLLBACK) since it is handled automatically. But you should still do the TRY / CATCH.

   Even better would be to change the `WHERE` condition to be a simple, sargable expression:

   ```sql
   WHERE  tbl.[date_field] <= (@datenow - 86400);
   ```

Also, I wouldn't use the term "temporary table" to refer to the `DayTempTable` table since it is not, in fact, a temporary table (which is denoted by having either a single or double pound sign `#` as the leading character(s) of the table name).

Comment: So, the structure is like the following: every day, the logs are saved into the DayTempTable, and every 24 hours,a task in Windows executes the procedure in order to copy the data from the DayTempTable to FinalLogs table. The unix time has been set on design time, by request of the previous DBA. The procedure was created by me (a junior DBA,very junior), and it has worked fine (i have monitored the data every day for a month), and only when I needed to create a report for a certain day, I saw that  there were some missing data.